# IR absorption chart

Tags: ir-spectroscopy, databases

I am taking a course in structural determination of organic compounds. Right now, we are giving the IR spectra.

I am looking for a table, as detailed as possible, of the absorptions. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Your best bet is the internet...

Comment: Google is your friend!   http://www2.ups.edu/faculty/hanson/Spectroscopy/IR/IRfrequencies.html

Comment: I recommend you stick to the table your prof gave you, because that is the one that will have to do when you have your exam. Otherwise Hesse, Meier, Zeeh surely has an English edition nowadays.

Comment: Thanks @Karl for bringing this book into my attention. It is highly rated on Amazon. Will try to buy it one day.

Comment: @Karl Of course there is (_some_ of the entries [here](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=hesse+meier+zeeh&adgrpid=69761543503&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI3-a09-r87AIVlOd3Ch38SQMPEAAYASAAEgKpovD_BwE&hvadid=352799477255&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=9041582&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=e&hvrand=9932938029015534331&hvtargid=kwd-301821995428&hydadcr=24125_1739945&tag=googhydr08-21&ref=pd_sl_1q69xkfz7j_e)). I like to complement HMZ with Ernö Pretzsch's compilations from the other school in Zurich, too ([Springer](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540938095)) and still have an edition with the CD.

Comment: The more detailed such a table is, the more time you will spend on it. Especially during a written exam, this is not good for you. In addition, a beginner's course intends to teach you _concepts_ about the experiments, and plausible results. In an exam, it may be much more useful to extract from the IR spectrum «plausible hints about an aromatic system, a halogen and  nitrile group» and _to complement_ these data by MS/NMR (e.g., o/m/p substitution) like in a typical synthesis lab. Despite a good IR spectrum may tell you substitution patterns (not so much the low resolution copies in a class).

Answer (score 1):

A very nice comprehensive set of IR absorption group frequencies were compiled seventy decades ago in the Journal of Optical Society of America by Colthup, 1950, 40, 397-400.

It is freely available if you search "*Spectra-structure correlations in the infra-red region*" by Colthup in Google Scholar.

You should memorize some standard frequencies of very common functional groups.